# I'm struggling with being able to close a simple widget using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have some Python experience and wish to learn about GUI development using tkinter.

I can create a simple widget, but when I try to close the window, things "hang" and nothing happens. Only by restarting the Python kernel can I get the window to close.

I'm running Python 3.7 using Spyder and, based upon some simple examples I've found in other forums tried the following:

```
  import tkinter

  root = tkinter.Tk()
  root.title("Hello!")
  simple_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Easy, right?")

  closing_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Close window", 
  command=root.destroy)

  simple_label.pack()
  closing_button.pack()

  root.mainloop()
```

As I mention above, the window does not close when I click my mouse on the Close Window button. I just get the "swirly" indicator on my Mac indicating the program is not responding. However, I am able to perform calculations in the Spyder console.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your code. When you call that file from a console like `python mymodule.py`, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works fine from the terminal. But it doesn't work as desired when I run the file from within Spyder. Am I missing something obvious? (My Python experience is somewhat limited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine, but what you should do is open the program in the Python IDLE that comes when you download Python. When you run the program it should open up the Python Launcher, which allows you to interact your your GUI (And it will let you close click the close button) I am using a Mac and everything works fine.

Comment: Okay, I see--just got it to work. I'll now start doing everything in IDLE. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I was analyzing your case and we BOTH did something we didn't notice after.

When you use the "root.destroy" command, you should add parenthesis after.. Had the same thing happening to me

Added root.destroy **( )**  and worked flawlessly. <-- Use it without SPACES

Hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: In the OP's code, they are doing it correctly. The `command` parameter requires a reference to a function. In your case `root.destroy()` would be called as soon as the button is created.

Comment: It does not end after the button is created, I'm testing it along the way, maybe it's something related with jupyter notebook, not sure about it tho.

Comment: If you do `command=root.destroy()` it absolutely will call `root.destroy()` when the button is created. That's simply how python works. `root.destroy()` is called and the result is passed to the `command` option.